# Command [/usr/local/bin/dub path /var/lib/kafka/data writable] FAILED ! in Kafka

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I want to deploy a kafka in k8s cluster.I have a zookeeper which is deploy without any issue but for deploying the kafka it doesnot become running and stuck in crashloopbackoff.I check it logs and here is its log:

```
===> User uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
===> Configuring ...
===> Running preflight checks ...
===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...
Command [/usr/local/bin/dub path /var/lib/kafka/data writable] FAILED !
```

And here is my deployment file :

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-broker0
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: kafka
        id: "0"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
        id: "0"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kafka
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
          value: PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zoo1:2181
        - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
          value: "0"
        - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
          value: input:1:1, output:1:1
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/kafka/data
          name: kafka-data
      volumes:
      - name: kafka-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: kafka-data
```

I find this [link](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/issues/127) but in all sulotions the talk about deploy with docker and there isn't any solution for kubernetes.Also I try to add `user: root` or `user: "0:0"` but I couldn't find out how to add it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found a way to do a similar thing to the [link you are talking about](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/issues/127) but using Kubernetes.

In the pod configuration you can add:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: kafka
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.2
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          runAsGroup: 0
```

I'm not sure whether it's the proper solution but it should work.
In my case I cannot use it as a solution because my cluster configuration does not allow me to run the pod as root.

Perhaps you can try to set `runAsUser: 1000` and `runAsGroup: 1000`. That's the ID I see when I run the image via docker. Although not sure if that's gonna work because I can see that the ID in your logs is the same.

```
===> User
uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
```

Comment: Thank you. I ran it with root and my problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you. I ran it with root and my problem was solved.